# UI components of java programs appearing as blank boxes

Tags: java, user-interface

As I run Java programs (like DbVisualizer and OpenProj) on my computer, some UI components like buttons, images, check boxes, scrollbars, etc. show as blank boxes. Not rarely some of these components first appear normally when you open the program and then go blank as you mouse over them.

I have already updated JRE and video drivers and also tweaked JAVA_OPTS with `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true;-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false;`, as recommended in Java forums, but none of these proposed solutions have worked so far.

I don't believe this is an OS specific issue, since I checked some other PCs with the exact same configuration of OS (Windows Vista) and hardware and many of them don't present that problem.

A screenshot of this situation can be seen here:

[image: GUI Blank Boxes]

Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me what happens if you change focus from window & again get back to it??? because i had this kind of problem.
Solution of my problem was in coding i had written setVisible true what not at proper location.

Comment: Seems to be something with double buffering / erase / missing repaint. Could be a Windows invalidate event or so. So maybe something in Windows, a screen capture tool running in the background. Select an other Windows theme.

Comment: Which Java version? Or did you try different versions already?

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago with 2 monitors attached on the same machine. The application was fine on one monitor and blank boxes on the second. Basically if i was putting the window to stay half on one monitor and half of the other, half of the window was fine and half was  blank boxes. it was a problem with the graphics card device driver. Try reinstalling it or reset all its settings. The application was fine on any other computer with similar hardware.

Answer (score 5):

Those JAVA_OPTS must be separated by spaces and not semi-colons!

Connect to the application with jVisualVM and verify that the "JVM Arguments" section contains all your desired options.

Answer (score 4):

While using windows basic theme I would often find numerous graphical glitches. Moving a window would create a trail behind itself over background windows and UI controls at times would not appear until moused over.

As already suggested, try using the windows aero theme and just turn off transparency if you don't like the aero look.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem more like a graphics driver issue. Note how things that are missing are images (icons, checkboxes) which are drawn by transferring the bitmap data directly to the graphic card. The `sun.java2d.noddraw=false` and `sun.java2d.d3d=false` are more of a hacks in this case, really.

What I would do is:

- check if I am using the latest version of Java (wouldn't hurt to switch to a 64-bit java if you are using a 64-bit system)
- check your graphics drivers, make sure they are the latest version
- check Windows service packs

Also try using changing the [Look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html); maybe this will help.

Comment: Nitpick: switching to a 64-bit version of java could hurt actually, since there's no auto-updating feature provided for it on windows. Oracle is made of pure win and sweet user friendliness! No bacon though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that disabling DirectDraw will fix this and your attempt to disable it was unsuccessful.

As noted by Ryan, the options appear to be formatted incorrectly. Remove the semicolons and put a space between, or better still, only use `sun.java2d.d3d=false`. The `sun.java2d.noddraw` flag was obsoleted [Java SE6u10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#noddraw) and setting to true now has the same effect as setting `sun.java2d.d3d=false`. There is no need to set both.

The effect of the incorrect formatting can be seen in the code below:

```
public class WrongArgs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("sun.java2d.noddraw: " + System.getProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw"));
        System.out.println("sun.java2d.d3d: " + System.getProperty("sun.java2d.d3d"));
    }
}
```

Running this code with args: "-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true;-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false;" produces:

> sun.java2d.noddraw: true;-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false;
>
> sun.java2d.d3d: null

Running with args "-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false"

> sun.java2d.noddraw: true
>
> sun.java2d.d3d: false